# using the jquery tablesorter plugin-- possible to have a static column?

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

what I mean by static column is one that is on the same table, but doesn't move when the other columns are called upon to sort

Comment: At the top of the data, at the bottom, or in the middle?

Comment: basically i want a far left column that provides a rank for each row.  im not sure i understand your question

Comment: You said "static row" in your question. I was asking where you wanted the static row to be -- at the top, at the bottom, or in the middle somewhere. Your comment there makes me think you want a static *column* rather than a static row. Perhaps you can clarify?

Comment: thank you for catching that!  i have made the appropriate edits, and yes i do mean column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tried it, but I wonder if a `tfoot` element or a 2nd `thead` (after the sort headers) would be left alone... Those would handle the "at the top" and "at the bottom" cases, if it works.

*(I've made this an answer, but a CW one because it's completely hypothetical. Doesn't mean it may not be right, but if it is, it seems wrong to get rep from a guess...)*

Comment: interesting answer, i will have to play around with thead